# How do I figure out how many possible combinations are in a passcode limited per character location?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have the following type of passcode that is limited in characters based on the position. It's a 12-digit long code.

In the params is the amount of possible characters allowed using `0-F` within their allow positions:

```
(4)(8)(15)(4)(8)(15)(4)(8)(15)(4)(8)(15)
```

The lowest possible value would be:

```
000000000000
```

And the highest possible value would be:

```
37F37F37F37F
```

How can I figure out the total possible combinations of this mixed code?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand, but it sounds like you have four options for the first character, eight options for the second character, 12 options for the third character, 4 options again for the fourth character etc...  Apply multiplication principle.  The total number of outcomes is the product of the number of options at each step.

Comment: So it's as simple as `4*8*12*4*8*12*4*8*12*4*8*12` ~ 21.7 billion?

Comment: Given my interpretation of the problem, yes it is.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `4*8*15*4*8*15*4*8*15*4*8*15` ~ 53 billion